# Wordpress site on EC2 instance suddenly superslow

Tags: amazon-ec2, wordpress

Set up a wordpress page the other day following [this](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/wordpress-in-the-cloud-with-ec2-and-wpi/2) guide.
The site was up and running, loading quickly and all was well, until today.

Suddenly, loading the [site](http://ec2-204-236-133-236.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/) takes forever and doesn't even work properly, the page shows up in an incomplete fashion.

I tried rebooting the instance but that didn't help.

The only actions I've taken on the server is to create an elastic IP, and to point a domainname to that IP. But I don't see how that could've slowed down the page.

Any thoughts on what could have caused this and on a solution to the problem?

Comment: Forgot to mention; I am running an AMI that has windows server edition installed.

Comment: What size instance are you running the site on?

Comment: micro-instance.

Answer (score 4):

Just go into your wp-config.php file and add the line
`define('RELOCATE',true);`
right above the line that says 'That's all! Stop editing!'
Then login to WordPress at your NEW ip address. It will work fine. Then just go to
Settings->General
 and update your site URL to the correct info. Be sure to scroll to the bottom and click Save. Your site will again function normally. Be sure to delete or comment out the `define('RELOCATE',true);` line that you added in wp-config.php
Source: my own experience and wordpress.org support forums

Comment: This is all true, and this works very well, but it's completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Awesome. This was a most excellent answer. I already had a medium instance but I shut it down and when it came back up it worked very slow. Thanks so much Jack

Comment: @MichaelHampton it is not irrelevant since wordpress has the bad habit of trying to reach old address and takes forever to load a page (exactly what happened to OP and still happens if you change IP/DNS after WP installation.

Answer (score 3):

The Amazon's Micro instances don't scale well with WordPress and other software that uses databases heavily. If you would like to keep the micro instance, I'll recommend install a caching plugin for WordPress or some caching software like Varnish to reduce the impact your database is making on your instance resource consumption (you're probably hitting 100% CPU and being hammered for that).
If you can change your instance, try the small or medium instances and you'll have no problem with your WP installation.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this issue today (I run a micro instance as well)... my WordPress site was working perfectly until I created an elastic IP, and in doing that, my public DNS name was changed.  I noticed that when I tried to access my WordPress site, it was trying to access my old public DNS name.

Apparently, when you set up your WordPress site, part of the installation process grabs the site's public DNS name and stores it in the WordPress MySQL table.  It was a simple fix for me... loaded up `phpMyAdmin`, went to the `wordPress` database, and modified some values in the `wp_options` table.  I ran the following MySQL query (**make sure you back up your database just in case**):

`update wp_options set option_value = replace(option_value, 'ec2-<old_ip>', 'ec2-<new_ip>')`

Where `<old_ip>` is the old IP that was used in your public DNS, and `<new_ip>` is the new one.  This will find and replace your old ec2 DNS name and replace it with the new one... voila!  All should be well.

Comment: ...may I ask why I was downvoted?

Comment: Probably because your answer doesn't seem to actually address the OP's problem, but reads like an anecdotal story sympathizing with the OP.

Comment: It looks fine to me, though one doesn't really need the "me too" part here.

Comment: @Magellan: how does it not address the problem?  I was getting slowness with WordPress after creating an elastic IP... exactly what the OP was experiencing.